Movie where population must stay the same
My girlfriend was describing this movie to me tonight and wants to watch it again, but she does not know the name of it. Here's what she recalls... A small group of people went to a town where the population sign stayed the same and when someone new came in, they had to kill someone to even out the population and keep it the same. She had a lot of emphasis on the population sign. I showd her some search results on Google, but nothing seemed to fit. Other details I asked her are below. Any help is much appreciated. 

Live action.
Watched on TV sometime between 2005 and 2013.
Could have been made anytime after 1980. 
American 


I believe you're looking for Population 436

A census-taker (Sisto) is sent to investigate why a certain small town has had the same population -- 436 residents -- for the last 100 years.
While traveling to Rockwell Falls in an assignment of the US Census Bureau, the surveyor from Chicago Steve Kady has two flat tires nearby the small town. The local Deputy Bobby Caine brings him to the town and the Mayor Grateman lodges him in a farm, where the gorgeous Courtney Lovett lives with her mother. Steve finds that Rockwell Falls, considered by the locals as the most perfect place on Earth, has the same population since 1860 and sooner he discloses the meaning and the dark secret of their creed of solidarity and steadfastness. [IMDB]

And the Wikipedia link for more information: [Wikipedia]

